# how to retrive location from a PFGeopoint - (Parse.com and Swift) and show it on the map with Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

There are some answer on this, but related to different problems and all in objective-c.
I save in a parse class "Position" positions of users with this:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var lat = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
var lon = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude

let myGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: lat, longitude:lon)
let myParseId = PFUser.currentUser().objectId //PFUser.currentUser().objectId

println("****** this is my geoPoint: \(myGeoPoint)")

func sendPosition(userOfPosition: User) {

let takePosition = PFObject(className: "Position")

 takePosition.setObject(myParseId, forKey: "who") //who
 takePosition.setObject(myGeoPoint, forKey: "where")
                                        takePosition.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

                                }


  sendPosition(currentUser()!)
```

so this is my result:
[image]

then I want to show them on map, but how? don't understand how to retrive latitude and longitude from "where" column the code below doesn't work:

```
   import UIKit
    import MapKit

    class MapViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locationManager : CLLocationManager!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



        var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        var lat = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
        var lon = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let anotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        anotation.setCoordinate(location)
        anotation.title = "my title"
        anotation.subtitle = " my subtitle"

        mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)

        println("****** Welcome in MapViewController")



        //MARK: (471) Crossing Positions
        //*******************************************************

        let myGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: lat, longitude:lon)
        let myParseId = PFUser.currentUser().objectId //PFUser.currentUser().objectId

        println("****** this is my geoPoint from map view controller: \(myGeoPoint)")


//        
//        var inspector = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
//                inspector.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
//                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
//                    if (success) {
//                        // The object has been saved.
//                        var the = inspector.objectId
//                    } else {
//                        // There was a problem, check error.description
//                    }
//                }
//        
//        
//        


        func filterByProximity() {
            PFQuery(className: "Position")
                .whereKey("where", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinKilometers: 500.0)     //(474)
            .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                objects, error in
                if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    println("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")
                    for near in proximityArray {
                        println("here they are \(near)")
                        if let position = near["where"] as! PFGeoPoint {
                        let theirLat = position.latituide
                        let theirLon = position.longitude
                    }

                        let theirLat = near["where"].latitude as Double
                        let theirlong = near["where"].longitude as Double
                        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theirLat, theirlong)
                        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
                        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
                        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                        let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        theirAnotation.setCoordinate(location)
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)

                    }
                }
            })
        }

        filterByProximity()


//        //update my position
//        
//        func exists() {
//        PFQuery(className:"Position")
//            .whereKey("who", containsString: myParseId)
//            .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
//            thisObject, error in
//                if let result = thisObject as? [PFObject] {
//                    println("here the result: \(result)")
//                    
//                    let gotTheId = result[0].objectId
//                    println("ecco l'id singolo \(gotTheId)")
//
//                            //******** update function ********
//                            var query = PFQuery(className:"Position")
//                            query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(gotTheId) {
//                                (usingObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
//                                if error != nil {
//                                    println(error)
//                                } else if let objectToupdate = usingObject {
//                                    println("else occurred")
//                                    objectToupdate["where"] = myGeoPoint
//                                    println("position should be updated")
//                                    objectToupdate.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
//                                    println("position should be saved")
//
//                                }
//                            }
//                            //******** end update function ********
//                }
//            })
//        }
//        
//        exists()

        //*******************************************************




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




}
```

**Update after first answers**

tried to check for optionals, but have this message:[image]
 after not down casting the double:
[image]
[image]

Comment: `near["where"]` is a PFGeoPoint object. This object has latitude and longitude properties

Comment: if use let theirLat = near["where"].latitude as Double
                        let theirlong = near["where"].longitude as Double I'v got a thread error, could you post the code?

Comment: `near["where"]` will return an optional. You need to unwrap it and check for possible nil

Comment: tried this, doesn't work but I'm new at Swift and optionals are a problem at now: let theirLat = near["where"].latitude as? Double
                        let theirlong = near["where"].longitude as? Double
                        if theirLat == nil || theirlong == nil {
                            println("error")
                        } else {

Comment: you should use `if let where=near["where"] as! PFGeopoint { let theirLat=where.latituide  let theirLon=where.longitude }`

Comment: Where should I put it? instead of    if near["where"] != nil {     maybe?anyway, I got a message "keyword where cannot be used as identifier"

Comment: Ok, change "where" to any other variable name. It should go in stead of the if statement you currently have in the for loop after the print

Comment: ok, added, now  error message "aspected type after 'as' " I updated the code in the question, it seems that doesn't accept PFGeoPoint as a type

Comment: Sorry, just a typo in my comment - if you look at the debugger you can see that it is actually `PFGeoPoint` - the second P is upper case

Comment: I got it :) I edited, but error still remains the same. in fact if I try to type your code, it doesn't autofill.

Comment: Have you added the Parse imports to the objective c bridging header for your project?

Comment: yes: #import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked. Was both a matter of optionals, and a matter of variables, I was using the wrong ones:

```
        //MARK: (471) Crossing Positions
        //*******************************************************

        let myGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: lat, longitude:lon)
        let myParseId = PFUser.currentUser().objectId //PFUser.currentUser().objectId
        var radius = 100.0

        println("****** this is my geoPoint from map view controller: \(myGeoPoint)")


        //MARK: *** let's look for other users ***

        var nearArray : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

        func filterByProximity() {
            PFQuery(className: "Position")
                .whereKey("where", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinKilometers: radius)     //(474)
                .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                    objects, error in
                    if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject] {
//                        println("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")
                        for near in proximityArray {
//                            println("here they are \(near)")

                            let position = near["where"] as? PFGeoPoint

                            var theirLat = position?.latitude       //this is an optional
                            var theirLong = position?.longitude     //this is an optional
                            var theirLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: theirLat!, longitude: theirLong!)

                            nearArray.append(theirLocation)

                            if nearArray.isEmpty {
                                println("*** ERROR! anyone close by ***")
                            } else
                            {
                                for person in nearArray {

                                    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.50, 2.50)
                                    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(theirLocation, span)
                                    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                                    let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                                    theirAnotation.setCoordinate(theirLocation)
                                    theirAnotation.title = near["who"] as String

                                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(theirAnotation)
                                }

                            }



                        }
                        println("****** in a radius of \(radius) there are \(nearArray.count) bikers ******")

                    }
                })
        }

        filterByProximity()
```

Answer (score 1):

the 'where' is a PFGeoPoint, you can just call latitude and longitude on them

Try something like this - I'm not 100% sure in Swift syntax, yet

```
if(geoPoint)
{
   if(geoPoint!.latitude)
   {
       let latitude = geoPoint!.latitude as double;
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi Nils, could you help me here? Xcode 6.3.2 this time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139304/xcode-6-3-2-cant-get-authorization-from-facebook-via-parse-com-swift