# How to download my object? (issue with optionals in old Xcode version)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Since I developed this my app with Xcode 6.2, I found some problems, many solved, but this one, maybe requires to rebuild my app again. 
In the code below, **filterByProximity** function gives an error.
I SUPPOSE is a matter of optionals (Nils Ziehn warned me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828847/how-to-retrive-location-from-a-pfgeopoint-parse-com-and-swift-and-show-it-on?answertab=votes#tab-top) about it). Another developer told me: "download the position object using cache, and then make the query".

Well, is it possible? how can I do it? here my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        var lat = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
        var lon = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let anotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        anotation.setCoordinate(location)
        anotation.title = "my title"
        anotation.subtitle = " my subtitle"

        mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)

        println("****** Welcome in MapViewController")



        //MARK: (471) Crossing Positions
        //*******************************************************

        let myGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: lat, longitude:lon)
        let myParseId = PFUser.currentUser().objectId //PFUser.currentUser().objectId

        println("****** this is my geoPoint from map view controller: \(myGeoPoint)")


//        
//        var inspector = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
//                inspector.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
//                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
//                    if (success) {
//                        // The object has been saved.
//                        var the = inspector.objectId
//                    } else {
//                        // There was a problem, check error.description
//                    }
//                }
//        
//        
//        

        //MARK: *** let's look for other users ***

//        func filterByProximity() {
//            PFQuery(className: "Position")
//                .whereKey("where", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinKilometers: 500.0)     //(474)
//            .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
//                objects, error in
//                if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject] {
//                    println("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")
//                    for near in proximityArray {
//                        println("here they are \(near)")
//                     
//                        let position = near["where"] as? PFGeoPoint
//                    
////                        if let position = near["where"] as! PFGeoPoint {
////                            let theirLat = position.latitude
////                            let theirLon = position.longitude
////                        }
//                        
//                            let theirLat = near["where"].latitude as Double
//                            let theirlong = near["where"].longitude as Double
//                            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theirLat, theirlong)
//                            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
//                            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
//                            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
//                            let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
//                            theirAnotation.setCoordinate(location)
//                            self.mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)
//
//
//                    }
//                }
//            })
//        }
//        
//        filterByProximity()


//        //MARK: *** let's update my position (on Parse) ***
//        
//        func exists() {
//        PFQuery(className:"Position")
//            .whereKey("who", containsString: myParseId)
//            .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
//            thisObject, error in
//                if let result = thisObject as? [PFObject] {
//                    println("here the result: \(result)")
//                    
//                    let gotTheId = result[0].objectId
//                    println("ecco l'id singolo \(gotTheId)")
//
//                            //******** update function ********
//                            var query = PFQuery(className:"Position")
//                            query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(gotTheId) {
//                                (usingObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
//                                if error != nil {
//                                    println(error)
//                                } else if let objectToupdate = usingObject {
//                                    println("else occurred")
//                                    objectToupdate["where"] = myGeoPoint
//                                    println("position should be updated")
//                                    objectToupdate.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
//                                    println("position should be saved")
//
//                                }
//                            }
//                            //******** end update function ********
//                }
//            })
//        }
//        
//        exists()

        //*******************************************************




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Comment: can you please just paste the code that is relevant and what is the line and content of the error message?

Comment: Hi Nils, You tried to help me with this one before, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828847/how-to-retrive-location-from-a-pfgeopoint-parse-com-and-swift-and-show-it-on?answertab=votes#tab-top. Now I'm building this app with new Xcode. but for now, I'd like to try the solution this developer proposed. download the database and make a query locally