# Displaying Annotations on MKMapKit by taking data from Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, mkmapview

So I am trying create annotations using the users current location. Before I connected my App to Parse I could save the info to the `NSUserDefaults` and it worked perfectly. Now that I'm using Parse I'm having trouble figuring out how to call the coordinates I saved in Parse in one view controller so that I can display the coordinates as an annotation in a different Map View controller. The current code I am using is

```
let userLoc = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("Location") as! [String : NSNumber]
Let userLat = userLoc["lat"]
Let userLng = userLoc["lng"]

var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLat as! CLLocationDegrees
var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLng as! CLLocationDegrees
```

So how do I modify this code in order to display the coordinates I saved to Parse? 
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828847/how-to-retrive-location-from-a-pfgeopoint-parse-com-and-swift-and-show-it-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31088629/3906189) is what you're looking for

The code:

```
        //MARK: (471) Crossing Positions
        //*******************************************************

        let myGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint(latitude: lat, longitude:lon)
        let myParseId = PFUser.currentUser().objectId //PFUser.currentUser().objectId
        var radius = 100.0

        println("****** this is my geoPoint from map view controller: \(myGeoPoint)")


        //MARK: *** let's look for other users ***

        var nearArray : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []

        func filterByProximity() {
            PFQuery(className: "Position")
                .whereKey("where", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinKilometers: radius)     //(474)
                .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                    objects, error in
                    if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject] {
//                        println("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")
                        for near in proximityArray {
//                            println("here they are \(near)")

                            let position = near["where"] as? PFGeoPoint

                            var theirLat = position?.latitude       //this is an optional
                            var theirLong = position?.longitude     //this is an optional
                            var theirLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: theirLat!, longitude: theirLong!)

                            nearArray.append(theirLocation)

                            if nearArray.isEmpty {
                                println("*** ERROR! anyone close by ***")
                            } else
                            {
                                for person in nearArray {

                                    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.50, 2.50)
                                    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(theirLocation, span)
                                    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                                    let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                                    theirAnotation.setCoordinate(theirLocation)
                                    theirAnotation.title = near["who"] as String

                                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(theirAnotation)
                                }

                            }



                        }
                        println("****** in a radius of \(radius) there are \(nearArray.count) bikers ******")

                    }
                })
        }

        filterByProximity()
```

Comment: What do I set the lat and lon to in PFGeoPoint?