# Xcode 6.3.2 - Can't get location via MapKit

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I'm rebuilding an app from Xcode 6.2 to 6.3.2

In my info.plist I set NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription with a string message, and Privacy - Location Usage Description with another string message.

I switched on capabilites/maps
I switched on capabilites/background modes/location updates

Imported MapKit and CoreLocation frameworks in build phases

I need to get single latitude and longitude because I will need them with Parse.

UPDATE after Imas145 answers

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak var anotationsCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceFilterLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0      //tot horizontal meters before sending an update on location
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .Follow
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }

    //MARK: - Helper - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        if let location = locationManager.location {

        var myLatitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
        var myLongitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude

        var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myLatitude, longitude: myLongitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)             //how much to show
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)     //how much to show
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

//        let anotation = MKPointAnnotation()
//        anotation.coordinate = location                         //was : anotation.setCoordinate(location)
//        anotation.title = "you are here"
//        anotation.subtitle = "City name"


//        mapView.removeAnnotation(anotation)
//        mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)


        var totalAnotations = mapView.annotations.count
        anotationsCountLabel.text = "\(totalAnotations)"
        distanceFilterLabel.text = "\(locationManager.distanceFilter)"
        println("latitude is: \(myLatitude)")
        println("longitude is: \(myLongitude)")


//        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        }

    }



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("problem1: error" + error.localizedDescription)

    }



}
```

Comment: maybe @Nils Ziehn could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `location` right after you have started location updates using `startUpdatingLocation()`. As the documentation says:

`The last location received. Will be nil until a location has been received.`

So instead, you need to handle it after the location has been determined. You can do that in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

Here is a quick implementation of that:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0      //distance before notifing a change
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()     //really starts monitoring position

        // move the code to delegate method

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        if let location = locationManager.location {
            var myLatitutde = location.coordinate.latitude
            var myLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude

            var myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)                 //how much to show
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)       //how much to show
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

            let anotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            anotation.coordinate = myLocation                       //XC 6.3.2
            anotation.title = "you are here"
            anotation.subtitle = "city name"

            mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)
        }

    }
}
```

You should also handle `locationManager:didFailWithError:` in case something went wrong.

EDIT:

To animate the pin drop, you need to do the following:

1. Add `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol to your class

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate
   ```
2. Add delegate to your `mapView`

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       mapView.delegate = self

       // rest of the code, location manager setup etc...
   }
   ```
3. Implement `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method

   ```
   func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
       let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
       pin.pinColor = .Red // or .Green or .Purple
       pin.animatesDrop = true
       pin.canShowCallout = true
       return pin
   }
   ```

Now the pin drops are animated.

Comment: got this error:    Objective-C method 'locationManager:didUpdateLocations:' provided by method 'locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)' in protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'

Comment: Did you copy-paste that code? I can run that code just fine in Xcode

Comment: I updated the question with my present state, maybe I made some error? is it right the way I Handled the error? (I'm new at Xcode)

Comment: It seems that there is a difference in declaration between iOS 8.x and iOS 9 (I'm using iOS 9 SDK). I edited my code to reflect the latest public declaration. If that doesn't work, remove the entire delegate method, then start writing it and let Xcode auto-complete it.

Comment: I wrote the method to be sure. now map shows my nation, but no pin, no city, no animation occur. Also, I updated your code in the question implementing some println. I.E.             println("the if occurred") doesn't show so the if statement doesn't happen :( console says error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

Comment: Are you using iPhone Simulator? If you are, go to Debug → Location and then choose one. This will fix the error and show the pin. Also, unless I have misunderstood your intention, do you wish to pin the current location? If so, you are adding a pin to coordinate 0,0, because `myLocation` is initialized with empty coordinate. I can give you some code to get that working too, if you want.

Comment: Oh! I refactored this            var myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLatitude, myLongitude) as was in the old code, and works well. but in the old version, I got the position and animation in didLoad. isn't it possible anymore? Anyway, yes, I'll be grateful for all the help and time you are giving me. Once this is fixed, I Will fight against the new version of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828847/how-to-retrive-location-from-a-pfgeopoint-parse-com-and-swift-and-show-it-on/31088629#31088629

Comment: I updated my answer to enable animation in pin drops

Comment: great, it works, if I'll need to use latitude and longitude in other functions, I can use something like         self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude  right? and if need to show info like street name, region, postal code, I will need CoreLocation? right?

Comment: As long as they are called after an initial location has been determined. To be sure, you can use `if let latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude { // we have a latitude } else { // CoreLocation hasn't determined location yet }`. If you call your other functions from `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` you can be sure there is a location.

Comment: problem: the pin is added permanently, it doesn't update responding to position, if the app goes in background, then comes back in foreground, a new pin is added each time

Comment: For that, you have to choices: either remove all annotations from the `mapView` before adding a new one: `mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)` or by enabling the built-in user-tracking functionality by adding this code to `viewDidLoad`: `mapView.userTrackingMode = .Follow` If you just need to show the user their current location without the need to add custom data to the callout view (the view that pops up when you tap a pin), I'd suggest to use the built-in tracking functionality. It's system-wide, simple to use and provides more consistent experience.

Comment: I implemented mapView.userTrackingMode = .Follow, 3 questions. Now the blue bar indicating that background location activity disappeared intact, I switched off capabilites/background modes/location updates, reading docs it says I shouldn't use if I don't need to show something FROM the map, your opinion? second: in the future I'll retrive others nearby users positons from Parse. since I do not use annotations anymore, will it be possible who something like name, image etc? (I will make another question on stackOverflow at that point). did I usestopUpdatingLocation() right way?

Comment: mapView's userTracking mode is only for displaying the location to the user, it won't replace actual location data. In your case, you should try to use both. Show the user their location using `userTrackingMode`, and for other locations (nearby users), use annotations. This will make it clear where you are and where others are. To do that, you will need location manager and location capabilities if you need to do that in the background as well.

Comment: ok, Now It's a bit more clear the use of background service. I'm looking for a "WAZE"like affect for users nearby. (don't know if you know parse, but could you take a look here? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139304/xcode-6-3-2-cant-get-authorization-from-facebook-via-parse-com-swift )