# Xcode 6.3.2 - can't get authorization from Facebook via Parse.com - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, parse-platform

Rebuilding an app from Xcode 6.2 to 6.3.2

Parse linking is working, as tested with their dummy code from guide.

I think the problem is in the authorization's request, something must be changed in the way Parse gets access to user info, but can't solve where.

**Update HINT 1:**
if I sign up, no problem, but if I stop and re-open the app, the problem is there, since auto-complete on **saveInBackgroundWithBlock** failed, there could be a problem there, but where?
**Update HINT 2:**
I see on Parse's site, that "sessions" keep growing each time i log in

got this error:

[image]

the code in which I request authorizations:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBLoginViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var fbLoginView: FBLoginView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func pressedLoginFB(sender: UIButton) {

        //MARK: facebook personlized login from 440
        //to start, request permissions
        PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile", "user_about_me", "user_birthday"], block: {
            user, error in

            if user == nil
            {
                println("BAD! user cancelled login")
                //add a uialertcontrolelr before pushing to app store
                return
            }
            else if user!.isNew
            {
                println("GOOD! - User signed up with Facebook")
                //now, ask facebook for user's data
                FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me?fields=picture,first_name,birthday", completionHandler: {
                    connection, result, error in
                    var resultDictionary = result as! NSDictionary
                    user!["firstName"] = resultDictionary["first_name"]
                    user!["gender"] = resultDictionary["gender"]
                    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
                    user!["birthday"] = dateFormatter.dateFromString(resultDictionary["birthday"] as! String)

                    let pictureURL = ((resultDictionary["picture"] as! NSDictionary)["data"] as! NSDictionary) ["url"] as! String
                    let url = NSURL(string: pictureURL)
                    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!) //in old Xcode was an optional
                    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                        response, data, error in

                        let imageFile = PFFile(name: "avatar.jpg", data: data)
                        user!["picture"] = imageFile as PFFile      //MARK: not sure about this downcast
                        user!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                            success, error in
                            println("hello")
                            println(success)
                            println(error)
                        })


                    })

                    }
                )
            }
            else
            {
                println("GOOD - User logged in with Facebook")
            }

            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mapNavVCID") as! UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


        })

    }

}
```

this is my personal user struct, made for decoupling Parse:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

import Parse

struct User {

    let id: String
    //    let pictureUrl: String
    let name: String
    private let pfUser :PFUser    //pfUser is private because I will use it only with our backend

    //this is a nested function, I use this design pattern because of getDataInBackgroundWithBlock
    func getPhoto(callback:(UIImage) -> ()) {
        let imageFile = pfUser.objectForKey("picture") as! PFFile
        imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            data, error in
            if let data = data{
                callback(UIImage(data: data)!)
            }
        })
    }

}

private func pfUserToUser(user: PFUser) -> User {

    return User(id: user.objectId!, name: user.objectForKey("firstName") as! String , pfUser: user)
    //  I cut off this:
    //  "pictureUrl: user.objectForKey("picture") as String," because now it is an image thanks to gePhoto function
}



//test on optionals "if user exists, give the value to the user constant,
//and return a User instance via pfUserToUser function"
// the "-> User?" is the reason why I have an optional in loginViewController on " currentUser()? "

func currentUser() -> User? {
    if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
        return pfUserToUser(user)
    }
    else {
        //if optional user doesn't exist, return nil
        return nil
    }    
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: One value in the `user` (`PFUser`) is probably nil. You can check this in the debugger or by in code, explicitly creating a value to check, for example `let id = user.objectId!`

Comment: updated the question with some note. Can't find that way you say. There could be a problem with saveInBackgroundWithBlock, but is crucial to solve it

Comment: Have you checked that a) user is valid and b) `user.objectForKey("firstName")` actually returns a value?

Comment: If you are struggling with saveInBackground why not just call save and block the thread? Also since this is a parse specific question I'd recommend reposting to parse's forums. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers