# Downcast from [PFObject] to [PFObject]

Tags: ios, swift, object, geolocation

So I am setting up this app where users can see their positions and also be able to see other people’s position. For the script I was following this question. [how to retrive location from a PFGeopoint - (Parse.com and Swift) and show it on the map with Xcode 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828847/how-to-retrive-location-from-a-pfgeopoint-parse-com-and-swift-and-show-it-on)

While I was writing the code I got an error at this line:

```
  if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject] {
```

saying:

> DownCast From '[PFObject]?' to '[PFObject]' only unwraps optionals:
>   did you mean to use '!'?'

So i tried to add:

```
 for object in objects as! [PFObject]{
```

Still i do get the same error.

To be honest i do not know what the Objects are.

I do not know how to fix this and would appreciate if any help on solving the problem.

Thank you

For those who would like the rest of the code, here it is:

```
func filterByProximity() {
            PFQuery(className: "location")
                .whereKey("where", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinKilometers: 5000.0)     //(474)
                .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                    objects, error in

                    for object in objects as! [PFObject]{

                    if let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject] {

                        print("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")
                        for near in proximityArray {
                            println("here they are \(near)")
                            if let position = near["where"] as! PFGeoPoint {
                                let theirLat = position.latituide
                                let theirLon = position.longitude
                            }

                            let theirLat = near["where"].latitude as Double
                            let theirlong = near["where"].longitude as Double
                            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theirLat, theirlong)
                            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
                            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
                            self.MapView?.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                            let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                            theirAnotation.setCoordinate(location)
                            self.mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)

                        }
                    }
                        }
                })
        }

        filterByProximity()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change you code to the code below:

```
func filterByProximity() {
        PFQuery(className: "location")
            .whereKey("where", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinKilometers: 5000.0)     //(474)
            .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                objects, error in

                if let objects = objects {
                   for object in objects{

                 let proximityArray = objects 

                    print("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")
                    for near in proximityArray {
                        println("here they are \(near)")
                        if let position = near["where"] as? PFGeoPoint {
                            let theirLat = position.latituide
                            let theirLon = position.longitude
                        }

                        let theirLat = near["where"].latitude as Double
                        let theirlong = near["where"].longitude as Double
                        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theirLat, theirlong)
                        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
                        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
                        self.MapView?.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                        let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        theirAnotation.setCoordinate(location)
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)
                     }
                 }
            })
    }

    filterByProximity()
```

This should get rid of the optionals errors. but I think there is a logical error in your code and it should be like this:

```
func filterByProximity() {
    PFQuery(className: "location")
        .whereKey("where", nearGeoPoint: myGeoPoint, withinKilometers: 5000.0)     //(474)
        .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
            objects, error in

            if let proximityArray = objects {

                print("****** here the proximity matches: \(proximityArray)")
                for near in proximityArray {
                    println("here they are \(near)")
                    if let position = near["where"] as? PFGeoPoint {
                        let theirLat = position.latituide
                        let theirLon = position.longitude
                    }

                    let theirLat = near["where"].latitude as Double
                    let theirlong = near["where"].longitude as Double
                    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theirLat, theirlong)
                    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
                    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
                    self.MapView?.setRegion(region, animated: true)
                    let theirAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    theirAnotation.setCoordinate(location)
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)
                }
            }
        })
}

filterByProximity()
```

Comment: Then the error moved down the If let proximityArray = objects as? [PFObject] and displaying the same downcast error

Comment: @TomJames please see my upated answer. it's basiclly you don't need casting just you neet to unwrap it

Comment: I i believe that was it. I received an error at line "If let position = near['Where'] as! PFGeopoint" saying "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not PFGeopoint. That might not have anything to do with the object?

Comment: Nvm, easy fix. Thank you for the help

Comment: please see the last update regarding the last error.

Comment: I am getting a thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION at "for object in objects!"

Comment: This might be becasue objects in `nil`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: getting error at "if let proximityArray = objects" saying "intilizer for conditional biding must have Optional type, not [PFObject]

Comment: Regardless the errors, there is a logical problem in your code. why you have a nested loop for the same object `objects` and  `proximityArray` which is the same?

Comment: I did se your update. I recived an error at var lat = locationManager.location!.coordinage.latitude. Do you have a second to go into a privat chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100746/discussion-between-ismail-and-tom-james).